# Viewing report in Secondary server

Tags: ssrs-2008

Is it possible to view reports using SSRS on the secondary server configured for log shipping.

Thanks,

Comment: I see you are new to the site. Please be sure to click the checkmark next to an answer if you feel it has answered your question. Thanks and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

You can in SQL Server 2005 Enterprise Edition and up. If you are using the Express Edition, then you're better off replicating the database you want to report on.